# Error sending message to a QueueChannel from chain in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration in on of my project. And following the is the flow with in my application. When ever I am publishing a messaged to "domainEventChannel" , it goes through the transformer and then  messages is sent to **inputFromTransformer** channel and  from this as message is in chain it goes through splitter , transformer and filter. I have configured **output-channel="domainEventQueueChannel"** ,which is a queue channel.

I am able to track messages till the filter, but they never reach the QueueChannel.

Can I not sent a message to queue channel from a chain  ?

```
<int:transformer ref="partitionlessTransformer" method="transform"
        input-channel="domainEventChannel" output-channel="inputFromTransformer" />

   <!-- Chain which has the output channel as queue channel-->
    <int:chain input-channel="inputFromTransformer"
        output-channel="domainEventQueueChannel">
        <int:splitter ref="messageSplitter" method="split" />
        <int:transformer ref="jsonToObjectTransformer" />
        <int:filter ref="autopayModelProcessTransFilter"></int:filter>
    </int:chain>

   <!-- Queue Channel-->
    <int:channel id="domainEventQueueChannel">
        <int:queue capacity="10" />
    </int:channel>

     <!-- service activator which polls queueChannel -->
    <int:service-activator id="domainEventReconProcessServiceActivator"
         input-channel="domainEventQueueChannel" ref="domainEventReconProcessServiceActivator" method="intiateAutopayProcessTransRecon">
        <int:poller task-executor="domainEventReconProcessServicetaskExecutor" fixed-rate="10" >
            </int:poller>
    </int:service-activator>

    <task:executor id="domainEventReconProcessServicetaskExecutor"
        pool-size="10" queue-capacity="10" />
```

**Update 2#:**
When I add the following piece of config everything works fine. Message flows from queue channel to service activator:

```
    <int:chain input-channel="domainEventQueueChannel"
        output-channel="nullChannel">
        <int:service-activator id="domainEventReconProcessServiceActivator"
         ref="domainEventReconProcessServiceActivator" method="intiateAutopayProcessTransRecon" />
     <int:poller task-executor="domainEventReconProcessServicetaskExecutor"  fixed-rate="10"></int:poller> 
 </int:chain>
```

**Update 3#:**
With the chain in place I see the service activator's poller polling  the queueChannel. But without the chain , the poller is not starting at all I don't see poller logs at all.

With Chain in place:

```
2015-09-08 09:29:31.438 DEBUG 12817 --- [ask-scheduler-8] o.s.integration.channel.QueueChannel     : preSend on channel 'domainEventQueueChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=com.autopayprocesstransrecon.resource.DomainEvent@6ac4fcc0, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=7a91b5fb-b1aa-464a-2e1b-5309652a0520, id=25ae85aa-e0df-6c72-9a54-2e8dac3c5ddc, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1441718971437}]
    2015-09-08 09:29:31.438 DEBUG 12817 --- [ask-scheduler-8] o.s.integration.channel.QueueChannel     : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'domainEventQueueChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=com.autopayprocesstransrecon.resource.DomainEvent@6ac4fcc0, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=7a91b5fb-b1aa-464a-2e1b-5309652a0520, id=25ae85aa-e0df-6c72-9a54-2e8dac3c5ddc, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1441718971437}]
    2015-09-08 09:29:31.438 DEBUG 12817 --- [ask-scheduler-8] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inputFromTransformer', message: GenericMessage [payload=[{"eventInfo":{"eventId":"4535345353","eventName":"AutopayModelsExtracted","parentEventId":"4535345353"},"numOfAutopayModels":20,"message":"Published autopaymodels needed to be processed"}], headers={id=7a91b5fb-b1aa-464a-2e1b-5309652a0520, timestamp=1441718971410}]
    2015-09-08 09:29:31.438 DEBUG 12817 --- [ask-scheduler-8] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'domainEventChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload={domainevents={0=[{"eventInfo":{"eventId":"4535345353","eventName":"AutopayModelsExtracted","parentEventId":"4535345353"},"numOfAutopayModels":20,"message":"Published autopaymodels needed to be processed"}]}}, headers={id=438c63c8-1ed1-6516-110e-c3478aca35c8, timestamp=1441718971409}]
    2015-09-08 09:29:31.438 DEBUG 12817 --- [etaskExecutor-1] o.s.integration.channel.QueueChannel     : postReceive on channel 'domainEventQueueChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=com.autopayprocesstransrecon.resource.DomainEvent@6ac4fcc0, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=7a91b5fb-b1aa-464a-2e1b-5309652a0520, id=25ae85aa-e0df-6c72-9a54-2e8dac3c5ddc, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1441718971437}]
    2015-09-08 09:29:31.438 DEBUG 12817 --- [etaskExecutor-1] o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer           : Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=com.autopayprocesstransrecon.resource.DomainEvent@6ac4fcc0, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=7a91b5fb-b1aa-464a-2e1b-5309652a0520, id=25ae85aa-e0df-6c72-9a54-2e8dac3c5ddc, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1441718971437}]
    2015-09-08 09:29:31.438 DEBUG 12817 --- [etaskExecutor-1] o.s.i.handler.MessageHandlerChain        : org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#1 received message: GenericMessage [payload=com.autopayprocesstransrecon.resource.DomainEvent@6ac4fcc0, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=7a91b5fb-b1aa-464a-2e1b-5309652a0520, id=25ae85aa-e0df-6c72-9a54-2e8dac3c5ddc, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1441718971437}]
    2015-09-08 09:29:31.438 DEBUG 12817 --- [etaskExecutor-1] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@72193fb5] (org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#1$child.domainEventReconProcessServiceActivator) received message: GenericMessage [payload=com.autopayprocesstransrecon.resource.DomainEvent@6ac4fcc0, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=7a91b5fb-b1aa-464a-2e1b-5309652a0520, id=25ae85aa-e0df-6c72-9a54-2e8dac3c5ddc, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1441718971437}]`
```

Without Chain:

```
2015-09-08 09:48:02.572 DEBUG 13043 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.i.splitter.MethodInvokingSplitter    : org.springframework.integration.splitter.MethodInvokingSplitter@53abfc07 received message: GenericMessage [payload=[{"eventInfo":{"eventId":"4535345353","eventName":"AutopayModelsExtracted","parentEventId":"4535345353"},"numOfAutopayModels":20,"message":"Published autopaymodels needed to be processed"}], headers={id=f477f025-e92f-f896-9ac4-2ce1b91fb895, timestamp=1441720082572}]
2015-09-08 09:48:02.574 DEBUG 13043 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler       : org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler@2c8c16c0 received message: GenericMessage [payload={"eventInfo":{"eventId":"4535345353","eventName":"AutopayModelsExtracted","parentEventId":"4535345353"},"numOfAutopayModels":20,"message":"Published autopaymodels needed to be processed"}, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=f477f025-e92f-f896-9ac4-2ce1b91fb895, id=1364077a-6d5c-87f9-7d7c-3d144e45d661, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1441720082574}]
2015-09-08 09:48:02.599 DEBUG 13043 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.filter.MessageFilter     : org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter@80bfa9d received message: GenericMessage [payload=com.autopayprocesstransrecon.resource.DomainEvent@fd57501, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=f477f025-e92f-f896-9ac4-2ce1b91fb895, id=c2a324c8-9eb0-66e0-73a1-5595ed87b3ae, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1441720082599}]
hey I am in filter and my result would betrue
2015-09-08 09:48:02.599 DEBUG 13043 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.channel.QueueChannel     : preSend on channel 'domainEventQueueChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=com.autopayprocesstransrecon.resource.DomainEvent@fd57501, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=f477f025-e92f-f896-9ac4-2ce1b91fb895, id=c2a324c8-9eb0-66e0-73a1-5595ed87b3ae, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1441720082599}]
2015-09-08 09:48:02.599 DEBUG 13043 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.channel.QueueChannel     : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'domainEventQueueChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=com.autopayprocesstransrecon.resource.DomainEvent@fd57501, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=f477f025-e92f-f896-9ac4-2ce1b91fb895, id=c2a324c8-9eb0-66e0-73a1-5595ed87b3ae, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1441720082599}]
2015-09-08 09:48:02.599 DEBUG 13043 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inputFromTransformer', message: GenericMessage [payload=[{"eventInfo":{"eventId":"4535345353","eventName":"AutopayModelsExtracted","parentEventId":"4535345353"},"numOfAutopayModels":20,"message":"Published autopaymodels needed to be processed"}], headers={id=f477f025-e92f-f896-9ac4-2ce1b91fb895, timestamp=1441720082572}]
2015-09-08 09:48:02.599 DEBUG 13043 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'domainEventChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload={domainevents={0=[{"eventInfo":{"eventId":"4535345353","eventName":"AutopayModelsExtracted","parentEventId":"4535345353"},"numOfAutopayModels":20,"message":"Published autopaymodels needed to be processed"}]}}, headers={id=bf6f4f20-52bb-27e4-df97-4112ad4be3b5, timestamp=1441720082571}]
2015-09-08 09:48:03.616 DEBUG 13043 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2015-09-08 09:48:04.634 DEBUG 13043 --- [ask-scheduler-4] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
```

Answer (score 1):

That simply means the message is not passing the filter.

(The filter is dropping the message).

Comment: Hi Gary . The filter is returning "true" but still the message is not going through. When I added a service activator within the chain after the filter  the message is coming to the service activator

Comment: In that case, the message should arrive in the queue channel with no issues; turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages through the flow.

Comment: Hi Garry. Upon further investigation what i found that messages are delivered to the queue but they are never picked up by the service activator. I created the service activator so that multiple threads can process messages in queue channel, but looks like service activator doesn't process those messages in the queueChannel. Am I doing anything wrong from the service activator configuration perspective  ?

Comment: When I moved the service activator to a chain as mentioned above under Updated2# , things started working fine. So do I need to have a chain for service activator to work with queueChannel ?

Comment: No; it does not need to be in a chain; DEBUG logging is your friend.

Comment: I have enabled DEBUG which give doesn't me enough information on why it will not enable the poller when I start the application  { updated logs in section 3 above }. I will try to check your examples on git hub and see.